# NPM gives error on installing parcel-bundler

Tags: npm, node-gyp, parceljs

On installing parcel bundler using npm, i get the below error. I am installing parcel-bundler as a dev-dependency. No idea on how to resolve this issue as i am just learning nodejs. Thanks in advance. Thanks in advance.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\complete-node-bootcamp-master\complete-node-bootcamp-master\4-natours\after-section-11\node_modules\deasync
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./build.js
npm ERR! `win32-x64-node-16` exists; testing
npm ERR! Problem with the binary; manual build incoming
npm ERR! stdout=
npm ERR! err=null
npm ERR! Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56991/af229b8d-e127-428b-810a-c65a6537e2d9
npm ERR! For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
npm ERR! Debugger attached.
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.3.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.0 found at "C:\Python39\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14) 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:404:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"      
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd E:\complete-node-bootcamp-master\complete-node-bootcamp-master\4-natours\after-section-11\node_modules\deasync
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed
npm ERR! Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pantm\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-24T15_53_50_199Z-debug.log
```

Comment: what is your node version? what is the command you've used to install `parcel`?

Comment: Hi.. resolved by updating Visual Studio and python...

Answer (score 0):

Check for the Visual Studio version you have installed.
You can clearly see in error that no supported Visual Studio installation was found.

```
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
```

Visual Studio version 2015 or newer is required.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I got over it by changing the project folder name. Apparently, npm or parcel (don't really know) won't accept certain characters on project folder title name. Removed the ampersand(&) on mine and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Yarn:

```
yarn global add parcel-bundler
```

Answer (score 0):

try use `npm i --ignore-scripts`

Answer (score 0):

updating the node version worked for me